# How to consume a REST web service with Flashbuilder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

I am creating a Restful WCF web service which will need to be consumed by FlashBuilder 4. Is this possible? If so, how can I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily.

```
<s:HTTPService id="service" url="http://domain.com/the/rest/path/" result="onResult(event)" resultFormat="xml" />
```

Then just need to do `service.send()`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the data services wizard.  Here is a good blog with a tutorial: http://technoracle.blogspot.com/2009/07/flash-builder-4-tutorial-2-restful.html